# How do I remove market listings?

Tags: farmville-country-escape

Pretty much self-explanatory.

As you can see, I have a really stupid lineup of listings:
[image: Wheat Wheat Wheat Milk]

When I attempt to click on them, which should retract the item back into my Barn (inventory), which has more than enough space left, this comes up:
[image: "Wheat can't be stored and must be sold!"]

**Is there any way to get rid; throw away (or at least modify if I cannot retrieve/trash the items) the market listings?**

Comment: Possible Answer: If you have active listings on your Market shop, it'll automatically be bought by Marie after 5-7 days. *Needs Verification*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove market listings, you have to wait until they are sold out.

This can take a long time depending on the group of players you are matched with to sell them.

I can confirm that Marie buys them automatically, like aytimothy commented, because it has happened to me a few times.